# MobileFirst Application Center Console App Icon for Native Apps

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I tried to deploy a native iOS app on MobileFirst Application Center Console and the app icon is not showing on the application center, instead its just showing the default icon.

I deployed 3 apps built on different frameworks on MFP Application Center and here are the results:

1. MFP App - App created on MobileFirst

   - Icon is showing on App Center Console as long as there is an image icon on the application resources.
2. Ionic App - App created purely on Ionic with no MFP

   - Icon is showing on App Center Console as long as there is an image icon on the application resources.
3. Native App - App created directly on Xcode

   - Does not show the app icon and only displays the default app center console icon.

Why is the icon not showing for native apps? We are currently deploying a native app and we want that the app icon will also appear on the app center console. We are using MFP v7.0

Answer (score 1):

We are working on a fix for this. Fix will be delivered in couple of days.

Comment: Hi @vin.app, so the fix will come as a patch for v7.0? Hopefully you can reply here as soon as the fix is available. Thanks

Comment: To receive the fix, though, you will need to open a PMR for the support team to provide it to you.

Comment: @IdanAdar I thought it will just be released as a patch like iFix? No?

Comment: Yes, and iFixes are delivered to customers via PMRs. They are uploaded to Fix Central only once every two weeks or so. So either you wait two weeks, or open a PMR to request to have the fix provided to you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed in the latest MobileFirst iFix.

Comment: Is the latest here? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg2C7000003 v7.0 of MFP. I'm just confused if its really there because the file name is IF2016...